# Regex to block ? parameter in url

Tags: regex

I have a pretty basic regex for a soundcloud link as follows:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?((www)?\.)?soundcloud\.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*/
```

It doesn't do much and I would like to block that kind of more complicated links that contain something else (`?fbclid=`) than only valid soundcloud information:

Invalid:

```
https://soundcloud.com/beat-one/done-lam/w-avlwV?fbclid=IwAR8TyDI-1ezXHrP1BfaBG1rLP8gTlEQeGJzKO0DGZl7h1i63VWqenV_yDI8
```

Valid:

```
https://soundcloud.com/beat-one/done-lam/w-avlwV
```

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^(https?:\/\/)?((www)?\.)?soundcloud\.com\/(?!.*\?fbclid=).*$` https://regex101.com/r/NRxwHz/1 Note that as www is optional is could also match .soundcloud

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it seems a little complicated to understant as i am quite a regex noob. Could you just specify that the link should not contain any `?`character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a pattern like `((www)?\.)?` matches optional www but could also match an optional `.`

I think you meant to use optional `www.` as a whole.

For the question mark part, you could match the beginning of the use and then use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!.*\?fbclid=)` to assert what is on the right does not match `?fbclid=`

If that is the case, you could match for example 0+ times a non whitespace char `\S*`

If you are not using the capturing groups  for further processing, you could also make them non capturing `(?:`

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?soundcloud\.com\/(?!.*\?fbclid=)\S*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EHIfa5/1)

If the link should not contain a question mark, you could simplify the lookahead to `(?!.*\?)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but `https://soundcloud.com/beat-one/done-lam/w-avlwV?fbclid=IwAR8TyDI-1ezXHrP1BfaBG1rLP8gTlEQeGJzKO0DGZl7h1i63VWqenV_yDI8
` still matches your regex unfortunately

Comment: @Wizzardzz Did you check the regex demo? https://regex101.com/r/EHIfa5/1 How are you using the pattern? What is the tool or language?